# How to use go get or go dep with GitLab subgroups

Tags: go, gitlab, godeps

I have a Go project that requires some dependencies from a private GitLab repository like `git.mydomain.com/myteam/category/subcategory/project.git`.
But I'm getting this error.

```
ensure Solve(): remote repository at https://git.mydomain.com/myteam/category.git does not exist or is inaccessible: : exit status 128
```

Comment: Solution for SSH: https://stackoverflow.com/q/63932562/8103271

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This issue is discussed at length on the [GitLab support tracker](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/37832).

TL;DR; It's (intentionally) [broken for private repos](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/37832#note_53668438):

> Is [your group] private? If so, this is expected behavior, and I would recommend reading the discussion from [#1337 (comment 36293613)](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/1337#note_36293613) onwards. In this case, we have decided to maximize security/privacy at the slight expense of usability. The recommended workaround is to specifically add .git to your URL.

The only solution I've found is to use [`go get`'s support for `.netrc`](https://github.com/golang/dep/blob/master/docs/FAQ.md#how-do-i-get-dep-to-consume-private-git-repos-using-a-github-token), which solves this both for `dep`, as well as modern Go modules.

1. Create a Personal Access token on GitLab with **api** scope:
   [image]
2. Create a `~/.netrc` file:

   ```
    machine gitlab.com
        login <your gitlab username>
        password <the token created in step 1>
   ```
3. Protect your `.netrc` file a bit:

   ```
    chmod 600 ~/.netrc
   ```
4. Profit

This should now work:

```
    dep ensure -add gitlab.com/<company>/<subgroup>/<project>
```

or

```
    go get gitlab.com/<company>/<subgroup>/<project>
```

If you're using a private GitLab installation, I trust you to replace `gitlab.com` with the appropriate hostname where applicable.

Answer (score -1):

I think the best solution would be to use a proxy-server like [athens](https://github.com/gomods/athens). You could add your Gitlab-Credentials and use it as proxy-server. Athens then would handle authentication.