# Unable to install go module via SSH (private nested repository)

Tags: go, gitlab, go-modules

**Steps to reproduce**

- Install Go 1.14
- Create a private organisation in Gitlab
- Create a private subgroup in the organisation
- Create a private repository in the subgroup
- Clone the repository locally
- cd to the repository
- Initialise new go module `go mod init gitlab.com/myorganisation/mysubgroup/myrepository`
- Commit and push
- cd to another go modules enabled repository
- Run `go get gitlab.com/myorganisation/mysubgroup/myrepository`

**Got error:**

```
go get gitlab.com/myorganisation/mysubgroup/repo1: git ls-remote -q https://gitlab.com/myorganisation/mysubgroup.git in /Volumes/CS/go/pkg/mod/cache/vcs/a96c83d4d1395bc931a1a8ac402e8d8e494cc85efa9081cab02316963aa836ed: exit status 128:
        The project you were looking for could not be found.
        fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
        
        Please make sure you have the correct access rights
        and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score -1):

0. ~/.gitconfig:

```
    [url "git@gitlab.com:"]
        insteadOf = https://gitlab.com/
```

1.Set envs:

```
    GONOPROXY="gitlab.com/mycorp/*"
    GONOSUMDB="gitlab.com/mycorp/*"
    GOPRIVATE="gitlab.com/mycorp/*"
```

2. In go.mod file change path of your subgroup repo from     "gitlab.com/myorganisation/mysubgroup/myrepository" to "gitlab.com/myorganisation/mysubgroup/myrepository.git". Same for all subgroup repo import paths.
3. Go to your previous repository that requires above subgroup repo and call "go get -insecure gitlab.com/myorganisation/mysubgroup/myrepository.git"

After that go.mod must be updated and everything will start work fine.

Comment: You should not be setting `GONOPROXY` or `GONOSUMDB`. Setting `GOPRIVATE` alone is sufficient. And the correct value would be simply: `GOPRIVATE=gitlab.com/mycorp`